# Vehicles Emissions

Tags: climate-change

What is the suitable handheld device to measure the $\small\mathsf{CO_2}$, $\small\mathsf{CH_4}$ and $\small\mathsf{N_2O}$ emissions from the tailpipe of cars? and what the steps to convert the emissions that will measure by the handheld device in unit of (ppm) to the emission factor in unit of (kg/TJ)?

Comment: This question might be better suited on SE Engineering.

Comment: There seem to be many for [CO2](https://www.google.com/search?q=handheld+measure+CO2)  and CH4 but not N2O.

Comment: Are you sure you want to test for N2O instead of NO2? N2O is laughing gas. My experiences is that nitrous oxides, NOx, are emitted by internal combustion engines, not N2O. As for finding gas detection devices, look for "gas detector CO2", etc. on an internet search engine, there are many. You will need to contact a dealer if you want one device to test for many gases. You will not be able to get one detector for all gases as some gases interfere with the detectors for other gases. You may need to have more than one detection device.